# Adding back a file in git which was renamed to a different file name

Tags: git, git-mv

I had a file:

**a.cs**

which I renamed to:

**b.cs**

and made some logic changes in b.cs

Now I realized I need to re-add a.cs BUT keep b.cs.

I added back a.cs but I don't see it in the working directory and so I can't add it to the staging area and commit.

In the remote, I see that b.cs was renamed.

I assume it's because I renamed the original file instead of deleting it.

I know about the mv command but I don't know how to use it in this specific scenario

So what I need now, if it's possible, is to add back a.cs AND still keep b.cs?

**Updated**
Ok - so this is mistake.
The file was added back.
Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: I just don't see the file itself being added to the working directory and so I can't add it to staging... and so it's not in the remote

Comment: what happens if you do `git add a.cs`?

Comment: Nothing - tried it.
I think the whole issue is because I renamed the original file instead of deleting it so I just  need to tell git to "force add" that file.

I see that file b.cs in the remote is marked as "Renamed"

Comment: did you use `git mv` or just `mv` to rename the file originally?

Comment: The original file a.cs is now b.cs. I have added a.cs - so what do you mean by rename the original file?

Comment: can you add to the question the exact steps you did? the commands you used etc.

Comment: Updated original post

Answer (score 1):

`git restore -s <SHA1> -- a.cs`

Assuming that a.cs was committed earlier and it's SHA1 can be found in `git log`.

This will restore the file `a.cs` to the current working branch.

---

This is how SHA1 hashes look like `a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3`.